# Testing varnish cache rule

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have this:

```
if (bereq.http.X-Path ~ "[a-z0-9]+\.(js|css)$") {
            set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=259200";
    }
```

And I need to write a test.vtl to demonstrate that is working. I'm trying with:

```
client c1 {
    txreq -url "/content/css/main.min.aer234vcvb.css"
    rxresp
} -run
```

But it fails.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you - match your condition on `X-Path` incomming http header.
therefore in your `client`  you are not sending it in, and the condition just does not match.

see this sample, based on your config, but sending in X-Path.

```
varnishtest "Test Cache-Control on X-Path"

server s1 {
    rxreq
    txresp
} -start

varnish v1 -vcl+backend { 

  sub vcl_backend_response {
        if (bereq.http.X-Path ~ "[a-z0-9]+\.(js|css)$") {
           set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=259200";
    }
  }

} -start

client c1 {
    txreq -url "/content/css/main.min.aer234vcvb.css" -hdr "X-Path: /content/css/main.min.aer234vcvb.css"
    rxresp
    expect resp.http.Cache-Control == "max-age=259200"
} -run
```

you might want to check against `bereq.url`  and not `bereq.http.X-Path` ?!